# Alternating Upper and Lower case characters

Tags: python

I need assistance with my code. it basically takes an input and then prints the string with the alternate char being upper case.

I need a way to collect all chars into one variable

```
newString = input("Please enter a word ")
output = newString 
letters =len(output)
b = 0

while b < letters:
if b%2 == 0:
    printonelower=output[b].lower()
else:
    printoneupper=output[b].upper()
b = b+1


print(output)
print(letters)
print(printonelower + printoneupper)'
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Show a sample input/output. Otherwise you will just waste everyone's time including yours in answering unnecessary doubts and clarifications

Comment: *I need a way to collect all chars into one variable.* Then use just one variable instead of two? You can have a `list` called `result` and then `result.append()` in your conditions instead.

Comment: Your code looks like it's almost there. I see two changes that need to be made:1) Instead of having separate variables for the upper and lower case, use one. 2) Use `+=` to update this variable instead of `=`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you would want something like:

```
letters = "hello"
upper = True
new_letters = []
for l in letters:
    if upper:
        new_letters.append(l.lower())
        upper = False
    else:
        new_letters.append(l.upper())
        upper = True
new_letters = "".join(new_letters)
print(new_letters)
```

This returns`hElLo`

Comment: You are welcome, remember to accept it as an answer if it fits your problem.

Answer (score 1):

ok let's have fun too:

```
words = "this is a test"
result = "".join([str.upper, str.lower][i % 2](c) for i, c in enumerate(words))
print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
output = "wonderful" 
letters = len(output)
b = 0
word = []

while b < letters:
    if b % 2 == 0:
        word.append(output[b].lower())
    else:
        word.append(output[b].upper())
    b = b+1

print(''.join(word))
```

This returns wOnDeRfUl

Answer (score 0):

Another way of accomplishing the same task would be to store an iterable of the functions you want called on the string, and use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to loop over it repeatedly

```
from itertools import cycle

def apply_by_character(s, funcs=(str.upper, str.lower)):
    return "".join([f(c) for c, f in zip(s, cycle(funcs))])

print(apply_by_character('transition'))
# TrAnSiTiOn
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following.

```
letters="this is a test"
x=0
for i in letters:print(end=(2*i).title()[x]);x^=i.isalpha()
```

Output

```
ThIs Is A tEsT
```

Answer (score 0):

One line using genexpression

```
>>> input_string = 'Blahfasel'
>>> ''.join((c.upper() if i % 2 == 0 else c.lower() for i, c in enumerate(input_string)))
'BlAhFaSeL'
```

Answer (score 0):

let suppose the given string is like 'string' all lower case and we have to convert it into string like 'StRiNg' or 'sTrInG'.

so we can do this as write below:

take input with **input()** method and use **enumerate()** function to take hold the index of each letter in the input string at every iteration

with **python3:**

```
for index,letter in enumerate(input()): #input : 'string' or 'STRING'
    print(letter.upper() if index%2 == 0 else letter.lower() , end="") # ternary operator 
#output : 'StRiNg'


for index,letter in enumerate(input()): #input : 'string' or 'STRING'
    print(letter.lower() if index%2 == 0 else letter.upper() , end="") # ternary operator
#output : 'sTrInG'
```